# URL "civicrm/a/#" breaks the UI

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Hello dear colleagues.

Yesterday I updated a Drupal 8 site to 5.35.1.  Afterwards many of menu URLs become replaced/injected with a "civicrm/a/#" string, for example domain.tld/civicrm/a/#/mailing/new or domain.tld/civicrm/a#/status; and the UI returns a blank page, not a white screen, but a page with no CiviCRM body content (see attached image).

Once this occurs the CiviCRM menu system is no longer active (clicking on any other CiviCRM menu does nothing).

I have also now done a net new composer based install (new o/s path and new DB) this time on Drupal 9 CiviCRM 5.35.1, and precisely the same problem occurs.

This is a CPanel Centos VPS server.

Your kind help is most appreciated.

[image: 'blank screen']

Comment: Check the browser console for javascript errors.

Comment: Yup, an error:
GET https://domain.tld/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/angular-modules.0151d081eb0d6bca491cb18a24b0e3a7.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Similar files are present, but not the one called for:
./sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/ contains these files
angular-modules.734b336b53a89d35f086d1ec2725ff98.json
angular-modules.a457cd187bd83f4d364e75f64e31a4fa.js
angular-modules.fad2cb417fc3a1d78b05c08b3b425667.json
crm-menubar.f296fb9639f644da7a6b92ebafc965ef.css
index.html

Comment: The sought after file angular-modules.257675892968fd001e376109006e4b65.js does not exist on the server o/s anywhere. So one has to think this is not due only to a misdirected resource URL.

Comment: I have set file permissions as root with these scripts, then flushed caches, reset resource URL's etc.  The problem persists. 

cd /home/domain/www-cmnty-drupal/web
chown -R domain:nobody .
find . -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= '{}' \;
find . -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \;

cd /home/domain/www-cmnty-drupal/web/sites
find . -type d -name files -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
for d in ./*/files
do
   find $d -type d -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
   find $d -type f -exec chmod ug=rw,o= '{}' \;
done

Answer (score 3):

I have repeated the new install, this time including this:

`composer config extra.enable-patching true`

The site now completely renders UI contents, such as the new mailing page or the status page.

So then, going to the troubled upgrade site, having first configured the install with these composer configurations:

`composer config extra.enable-patching true`

`composer config minimum-stability dev`

`composer config prefer-stable true`

`composer require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin`

`composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}`

and then again:

`composer update`

`composer civicrm:publish`

The upgrade site is now working.

Comment: Ah - that’s in the instructions :-) I figured you were troubleshooting beyond the instructions!

Answer (score 0):

This typically helps with angular caching issues ->  [it's a cache clear of sorts]
Administer -> System Settings -> Asset Caching -> Disable

If that worked -> toggle back to -> Auto

Sometimes I have to re-run composer civicrm:publish (some bower assets - only some - most were there) - were just not there post upgrade.

Comment: Turned off asset caching, didn't help.
GET https://domain.tld/civicrm/asset/builder?an=angular-modules.js&ap=TU%2B7DsIwDPyXzhELTGw8xIaEWvUDTGOlRqldJTZCIP6dJBPLPWTdyffpFvEWMXf7DjhYhHShiOMaBbyDlXZuSsthXRupwjQvyNqcqWR4YtWnF1c6bytegSJx%2BJOHYzU9ZrE0tUAvpngk9piqHRTU8g1CO47UUCk6TxAlDJieVIKPLHyRtIBqyXFoLYUHYFJ6ozPaZEkK99i0lYrsjOub/jSXgWXo9wc%3D&ad=5ac506248dab1161c99fc746fa401d2a net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'https://domain.tld/civicrm/asset/builder?an=crm-menubar.css&ap=q1bKTc0rTUoscs7PyS9SslJSNkwCQSUdpYzUzPSMEiUrEwMdpaSi1MTsgvzMPCDf3MyiFgA%3D&ad=0348f387b2bf1b8c985aa224ed4367d9' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://domain.tld/libraries/civicrm/core/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: Did you re-run composer civicrm:publish?

Comment: Hi KarinG - yes
# composer civicrm:publish
Publishing CiviCRM assets to web/libraries/civicrm
Generating CiviCRM asset map

Comment: Currently I am troubleshooting the net new install that shows the same problems.